# What is it the best UI for an event date?

Tags: html, css, forms, user-interface, user-experience

I'm building a website where you can set up a webpage of your event. I want that the user will be able to pick up the right date and that they won't be frustrated about clicking a ton of time on a date picker.
 Do you know about any UX study on this case? Any suggestion?
What is it the very best way to show it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually go with [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in a dropdown menu, but you might want to look into [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30560/datepicker-ux-for-single-and-multiple-calendar-mode).

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting. I like the Google Analytics solution.

Answer (score 0):

In worst case they will have to click 7 times (for changing months and to chose day at which event will occur). 
This is normal practice. It could help if you would use dropdowns for months and days, this would require only two clicks.